# Scala - ambiguous reference to overloaded definition -- with varargs

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disambiguate in Scala between methods with vararg and without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313929/how-do-i-disambiguate-in-scala-between-methods-with-vararg-and-without)

I am currently porting part of an application to scala and it uses the Oval library.  The method is question is the Validator.validate method.  It has [two](http://oval.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/oval/Validator.html#validate%28java.lang.Object%29) [signatures](http://oval.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/oval/Validator.html#validate%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String...%29):

```
List<ConstraintViolation> validate(Object validatedObject)
List<ConstraintViolation> validate(Object validatedObject, String... profiles)
```

The scala code looks generally like this:

```
def validate(toValidate: AnyRef) = {
  val validator = createValidator
  validator.validate(toValidate)
}
```

And the error message:

```
error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[INFO] both method validate in class Validator of type (x$1: Any,x$2: <repeated...>[java.lang.String])java.util.List[net.sf.oval.ConstraintViolation]
[INFO] and  method validate in class Validator of type (x$1: Any)java.util.List[net.sf.oval.ConstraintViolation]
[INFO] match argument types (AnyRef)
[INFO]       this.validator.validate(toValidate)
```

How can I get this be be unambiguous?

Comment: It does appear to be an ambiguous reference to an overloaded definition question on stack overflow.  Should I delete this post?  Although Rex Kerr did give an answer that wasn't on the original.

Comment: I recreated my answer there, and expanded it in two ways: a short form for what I wrote for methods, and an alternate that works for constructors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that this could be a duplicate of [How do I disambiguate in Scala between methods with vararg and without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313929/how-do-i-disambiguate-in-scala-between-methods-with-vararg-and-without)

Basically, it is a known java-scala-interop problem, and the only workarounds involve extra Java adapters to make accessible in Scala.

Comment: Sometimes you can avoid the Java adapter by explicitly creating a `Seq` and using the [`_*` type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6051356/14379), eg

`validator.validate(toValidate, Array[String](): _*)`. 

See answers by Yawar and Teimuraz in the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3313929/14379).

Answer (score 5):

The only way I know of is to use reflection:

```
val ambiguous = validator.getClass.getMethods.filter(_.getName == "validate")
val wanted = ambiguous.find(_.getParameterTypes.length == 1).get
wanted.invoke(validator, toValidate).asInstanceOf[java.util.List[ConstraintViolation]]
```