# Scala Overloaded Method resolution issue. How to get the compiler to select the right method?

Tags: scala, overloading

```
[error] both method addVertex in class OrientBaseGraph of type (x$1: Any, x$2: <repeated...>[Object])com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex
[error] and  method addVertex in class OrientBaseGraph of type (x$1: Any)com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex
[error] match argument types (String)
[error]         val npNode = g.addVertex(f"class:$NPPhrase")
[error]
```

How do I get Scala to pick the method I am trying to call (the more specific one) ?

Oh and while in this context `g.addVertext(...,Nil)` is semantically equivalent, I still want to know how to solve the problem above.

Comment: Please show the code!

Comment: what would you do with the code ? it's just a method with a string as input.  ok maybe you need to see what `NPPhrase` is : `def NPPhrase = "NPChunkPhrase"`

Comment: Cheers, that one has a sensible answer (create a java disambiguation class"). voted to close.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler says right things to you.

`addVertex(f"class:$NPPhrase")` matches both `addVertex(Any)` and `addVertex(x$1: Any, x$2: Any*)`.
This happens because the `x$2` parameter may be empty and you can omit it when calling the `addVertex(x$1: Any, x$2: Any*)` (like `addVertex("whatever")`)

The options are:

1. Rename one of the methods.
2. Change the `addVertex(x$1: Any, x$2: Any*)` signature to `addVertex(x$1: Any, x$2: Any, x$3: Any*)`, so that it handles only calls with 2 or more parameters. (I assume your `addVertex(x$1: Any)` and `addVertex(x$1: Any, x$2: Any*)` behave the same for one parameter)

Comment: Yep :/ but I don't have access to that code. It's part of OrientDB. Surely Scala has some machinery for this to deal with legacy code ?

Comment: Well, that's a nice observation indeed.. I suppose you're using some kind of Java library for OrientDB. The problem is that Scala treats this as a compilation error for an obvious reason (it cannot choose by itself which method to invoke), but Java just runs the method without varargs and does not even complain.

Comment: It seems like this is a known issue. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313929/how-do-i-disambiguate-in-scala-between-methods-with-vararg-and-without