# Scala cannot resolve correct overloaded SLF4J method after flatmapping AnyRef*

Tags: scala, slf4j, scala-java-interop

I have a Java interface like the following:

```java
interface Bazz {
   void bar(String msg, Object args...);
}
```

I want to implement that interface (just happens to be in Scala) and use SLF4J logging to log the `args` parameter (for sake of this question, using another Scala logging library is not an option).

And the following (contrived) scala code:

```scala
object Foo extends Bazz {

  private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.getClass)

  def bar(args: AnyRef*) {
    log.info("Processing params: {}, {}, {}", args: _*)
    // ... do stuff with args...
  }
}

object Main extends App {

  val arr: Seq[String] = Array("A","B","C")
  val anyRef: AnyRef = arr  

  Foo.bar(arr)

}
```

}

Running `Main`,  I get the following output:

```
22:49:54.658 [run-main-0] INFO: sample.Main$ Processing params: WrappedArray(A, B, C), {}, {}
```

That's no good because the `:_*` is exploding the args, but the first element is an array.  For reasons I won't go into here, I actually need to pass the elements of that array as the single `Object[]` parameter to SLF4J's `Logger.info(String, Object[])` method.

Here's my first attempt:

```
def bar(args: AnyRef*) {
  val flatArgs = args.flatMap {
    case s: Seq[_] => s
    case x         => Seq(x)
  }
  log.info("Processing params: {}, {}, {}", flatArgs: _*)
  // ... do stuff with args...
}
```

This does not compiles with the following error:

```
[error] Main.scala:18: overloaded method value info with alternatives:
[error]   (x$1: org.slf4j.Marker,x$2: String,x$3: <repeated...>[Object])Unit <and>
[error]   (x$1: org.slf4j.Marker,x$2: String)Unit <and>
[error]   (x$1: String,x$2: Throwable)Unit <and>
[error]   (x$1: String,x$2: <repeated...>[Object])Unit <and>
[error]   (x$1: String,x$2: Any)Unit
[error]  cannot be applied to (String, Any)
[error]     log.info("Processing params: {}, {}, {}", flatArgs: _*)
[error]         ^
[error] one error found
```

How can I change this code to make it compile and also print `Processing params: A, B, C`?

Comment: Why do you use `AnyRef` ?

Comment: Modified my question to clarify this. It's about java interop.

Comment: It might sound awful but you might be able to pattern match the arguments out? That is, `case x: WrappedArray[_] => stuff`

Comment: I'd agree with @Ven. `anyRef: AnyRef` is the problem here. `args` is a one element array, where the first element is a `WrappedArray`. Use `foo("message",arr:_*)` to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: I'm stuck with the AnyRef* because that's how you implement Java interfaces with VarArgs.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313929/how-do-i-disambiguate-in-scala-between-methods-with-vararg-and-without

Comment: All - sincere apologies - I significantly re-wrote my question, as I realized I didn't quite understand my own problem. Please have another look and if you wish, revise your own answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer to my re-stated (now obvious) problem. Apologies for not having a clear question earlier:

```scala
def bar(args: AnyRef*) {
  val flatArgs = args.flatMap {
    case s: Seq[_] => s
    case x         => Seq(x)
  }.toArray.asInstanceOf[Array[Object]]

  log.info("Processing params: {}, {}, {}", flatArgs: _*)
}
```

Note: without the `asInstanceOf[Array[Object]]` the following occurs:

```
[error] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Array[Any]
[error]  required: Array[Object]
[error] Note: Any >: Object, but class Array is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: Object`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error]   }.toArray
[error]     ^
[error] one error found
```

Answer (score 2):

A problem here is that `Int` is an `AnyVal` which means that it is not an `AnyRef/Object`
Also an `Array` is not a `TraversableOnce`.

Now in the `foo` method we pattern match on the varargs.

```
def foo(msg:String,varargs:AnyRef*) { varargs.toList match {
  case (h:TraversableOnce[_]) :: Nil => log.info(msg, h.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[AnyRef]]:_*)
  case (h:Array[_]) :: Nil => log.info(msg, h.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[AnyRef]]:_*)
  case _ => log.info(msg,varargs:_*)
}}
```

There are 3 cases we deal with:

```
case (h:TraversableOnce[_]) :: Nil => log.info(msg, h.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[AnyRef]]:_*)
```

`TraversableOnce` is one of the Scala collections base traits; every collection I know of extends this (`Array` is not a collection, it doesn't extend it). It can contain either `AnyVal` or `AnyRef` but the actual items at runtime will be wrapped primitive (java.lang.Integer, etc.). So we can down cast from `Seq[Any]` to `Seq[AnyRef]` here and we should be okay.

```
case (h:Array[_]) :: Nil => log.info(msg, h.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[AnyRef]]:_*)
```

Just like we did with the `TraversableOnce`, turn it into a `Seq` and then downcast. The transformation into `Seq` will wrap any primitives for us.

```
case _ => log.info(msg,varargs:_*)
```

The general case in which `varargs` could be empty, or contain more than one entry.

Comment: Apologies...re-wrote my question. Please have another read through.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler variation on ggovan's, doing the match before calling `foo`:

```
val arr: Seq[Int] = Array(1,2,3)
val anyRef: AnyRef = arr 

val msg = "Another message: {}, {}, {}"
  anyRef match {
    case seq: Seq[_] => foo(msg, seq.asInstanceOf[Seq[AnyRef]]: _*)
    case x => foo(msg, x)
  }
```