# Not able to use Mockito ArgumentMatchers in Scala

Tags: scala, mockito

I am using ScalaMock and Mockito

I have this simple code

```
class MyLibrary {
   def doFoo(id: Long, request: Request) = {
      println("came inside real implementation")
      Response(id, request.name)
   }
}

case class Request(name: String)
case class Response(id: Long, name: String)
```

I can easily mock it using this code

```
val lib = new MyLibrary()
val mock = spy(lib)
when(mock.doFoo(1, Request("bar"))).thenReturn(Response(10, "mock"))
val response = mock.doFoo(1, Request("bar"))
response.name should equal("mock")
```

But If I change my code to

```
val lib = new MyLibrary()
val mock = spy(lib)
when(mock.doFoo(anyLong(), any[Request])).thenReturn(Response(10, "mock"))
val response = mock.doFoo(1, Request("bar"))
response.name should equal("mock")
```

I see that it goes inside the real implementation and gets a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure it goes inside the real implementation without matchers too, the difference is that it just doesn't crash in that case (`any` ends up passing null into the call).

When you write `when(mock.doFoo(...))`, the compiler has to call `mock.doFoo` to compute the parameter that is passed to `when`.

Doing this with `mock` works, because all implementations are stubbed out, but `spy` wraps around the actual object, so, the implementations are all real too.

Spies are frowned upon in mockito world, and are considered code smell. 
If you find yourself having to mock out *some* functionality of your class while keeping the rest of it, it is almost surely the case when you should just split it into two separate classes. Then you'd be able to just `mock` the whole "underlying" object entirely, and have no need to `spy` on things.

If you are still set on using spies for some reason, `doReturn` would be the workaround, as the other answer suggests. You should not pass `null` as the vararg parameter though, it changes the semantics of the call. Something like this should work:

```
 doReturn(Response(10, "mock"), Array.empty:_*).when(mock).doFoo(any(), any())
```

But, I'll stress it once again: *this is just a work around*. The correct solution is to use `mock` instead of `spy` to begin with.

Comment: The line ` doReturn(Response(10, "mock"), Array.empty:_*).when(.when(mock.doFoo(any, any))
` doesn;t compile. I changed it to ` doReturn(Response(10, "mock"), Array.empty:_*).when(mock.doFoo(any, any))` but it still doesn't compile

Comment: There needs to be a star after underscore. It compiles fine for me (after removing the extra .`when` :)) 
What error are you getting?

Comment: `doReturn(Response(10, "mock"), Array.empty:_*).when(mock.doFoo(any, any))` throws a bunch of compiler errors `Error:(24, 73) polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [T]()T
 required: Long
         doReturn(Response(10, "mock"), Array.empty:_*).when(mock.doFoo(any, any))`

Comment: ah ... you need `()` after any. Sorry about that (updating the answer).

Comment: doesn't work `[info] - should use mock module *** FAILED ***
[info]   org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: Unfinished stubbing detected here:
[info] -> at com.abhi.MyLibTest.$anonfun$new$2(MyLibTest.scala:24)
`

Comment: My line is `doReturn(Response(10, "mock"), Array.empty:_*).when(mock.doFoo(any(), any()))`

Comment: Ok, fixed again ... Try it now. But seriously, this is so confusing for a reason. The real solution is just don't use spies.

Comment: It works! thanks a ton. yes I will refactor my code and eliminate the need to do spies.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
doReturn(Response(10, "mock"), null.asInstanceOf[Array[Object]]: _*).when(mock.doFoo(anyLong(), any[Request]))
```

Comment: ```Error:(24, 10) ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method doReturn in object Mockito of type (x$1: Any, x$2: Object*)org.mockito.stubbing.Stubber
and  method doReturn in object Mockito of type (x$1: Any)org.mockito.stubbing.Stubber
match argument types (com.abhi.Response)
         doReturn(Response(10, "mock")).when(mock.doFoo(anyLong(), any[Request]))```

Comment: According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313929/how-do-i-disambiguate-in-scala-between-methods-with-vararg-and-without it is known scala problem. Ticket said that they fix it at some point. Do you use latest version of scala?

Comment: I can only use 2.11 as of now.

Comment: I changed to ugly version that workaround that problem.

Comment: Its not working. I checked in my code here which incorporates your version above. https://github.com/abhsrivastava/GuiceMockAny