# Ambiguous Reference to overloaded definition - One vs Two Parameters

Tags: scala, overloading, variadic-functions

Given the following companion object with overloaded versions of `apply`:

```
object List {
  def apply[T](): List[T] = new Nil
  def apply[T](x1: T): List[T] = new Cons(x1, new Nil)
  def apply[T](x1: T, x2: T): List[T] = new Cons(x1, new Cons(x2, new Nil))
  def apply[T](elems: T*): List[T] = 
    elems.foldRight(List[T])((elem, l) => new Cons(elem, l))
}
```

And the two instantiations

```
List(1) // Error - Ambiguity 
List('a', 'b') // Works fine
```

scalac complains about the first instantiation (**ambiguous reference to overloaded definition**) because both the single argument and the varargs method are [equally *specific*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2161551/664577).

Searching stackoverflow I've found that it is possible to [force the single argument method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290755/6645770). `List[Int](1)` will make the compiler use `def apply[T](x1: T)`.

My question is why does the second instantiation match `def apply[T](x1: T, x2: T)` without extra "hints"? In other words, why is the two argument method more *specific* than the varargs method where the single argument method isn't?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question we need to have a look at what happens when the Scala compiler has to perform overloading resolution. This is described in SLS 6.23.3 (for Scala 2.9).

Let's take a slightly simpler version of your example:

```
object Test {
  def apply[T](x1: T) = "one arg"                      // A
  def apply[T](x1: T, x2: T) = "two args"              // B
  def apply[T](elems: T*) = "var-args: " + elems.size  // C
}
```

And look at these three calls:

```
Test(1) // fails, ambiguous reference, A and C both match arguments
Test[Int](1) // returns "one arg"
Test(1,2) // returns "two args", not "var-args: 2"
```

Let's start with the first one. First, the compiler looks at the *shape* of each argument, which is a type that describes, basically, if the argument is a value or a function. Here, no difficulty, `1` is a very normal, boring value and its shape is the type `Nothing`.

Now it has a single argument `1`, of type `Nothing`, and finds all alternatives that are applicable to it. It finds two of them:

- `apply[T](x1: T)`: it takes a single argument of unbounded type, so it can receive a argument of type `Nothing`,
- `apply[T](elems: T*)`: it can be applied to any number (`0` included) of arguments of the same unbounded type, so it can receive a single element of type `Nothing`.

It there were only one, it would stop there and choose that one.

The second step is identical to the above, except this time it types each argument with an undefined expected type. Basically here it looks at the two alternatives left and finds out if they are applicable to the argument `1` of type `A <: Int`. No luck, they both are.
If you were two change `apply[T](x1: T)` to `apply(x1: String)` and leave the other one alone, here there would only be one applicable alternative left and it would succeed and stop.

Then the compiler computes the `relative weight` of each alternative left over each other. The SLS states that

> The *relative weight* of an alternative A over an alternative B is a number from 0 to 2,
>   defined as the sum of
>
> - 1 if A is as specific as B , 0 otherwise, and
> - 1 if A is defined in a class or object which is derived from the class or object
>     defining B , 0 otherwise.

At this point, there must be one alternative that has a higher score than all others, or there is an ambiguity error. We can ignore the "defined" part, they are defined in the same place.

- `A` is as specific as `C` because you can always call `C` with the single argument of `A`,
- `C` is as specific as `A` because of type inference: you can always call `A` with the argument of `C` since `A` can take anything (its parameter's type can be inferred to whatever we want). `C`'s parameters is seen as a `Seq[A]` so `T` is inferred as `Seq[A]` in `A` and it can call it. So `C` is as specific as `A`.

This can be seen if you change `A` to `apply[T <: Int](x: T)`: it goes all the way to looking for the most specific one, but this time type inference cannot find a way to make `A` applicable to `C`'s argument (a `Seq`) because it isn't a subtype of `Int`, so `A` is the most specific. Obviously, the same thing happens if you change `A` to `apply(x: Int)`, type inference can't even do anything.

This also explains why `Test[Int](1)` succeeds in calling the one argument version. The two final alternatives are identical, but `A`'s type parameter has been bound to `Int` and type inference cannot change it to fit `C`'s argument anymore.

Finally, applying the same logic gives you why `Test(1,2)` works fine:

- `B` is as specific as `C`: you can always call `C` with `B`'s arguments,
- but `C` is **not** as specific as `B`: no amount of type inference will manage to fit a single `Seq` into a method that takes *two* parameters.

So `apply[T](x1: T, x2: T)` is the most specific and there are no errors.

Basically for a var-arg and a normal method to produce an ambiguity, you they need to have the same number of arguments and a way to trick type inference on (at least) the last argument:

```
def apply[T](x1: T)
def apply[T](x: T*)
```

Or

```
def apply[T](x1: Int, x2:T)
def apply[T](x1: Int, x: T*)
```

And so on...

**Edit**: I wasn't sure at first whether the repeated parameter was seen as a `Seq[A]` or a `TupleX[...]` when looking for specificity. It definitely isn't a tuple, and auto-tupling has nothing to do with any of this.

Comment: "the intersection of overloading, polymorphism and type inference": don't let this paulpism mislead you. He just meant that if the compiler acted like it didn't have to infer anything, because it's like so obvious from the func application, then you wouldn't have to supply the type arg.

Comment: @som-snytt oh, I see. I'm sad, I thought he meant more generally that when these 3 orthogonal concepts intersect, weird things can happen.

Answer (score 3):

The fixed-arity method is always more specific than the var-arity.

`f(P1, P2)` doesn't apply to `(a, b, c, ...)`, which is how you can think of `f(P*)`.

Conversely, though, `f(P*)` takes the shape `f(p1,..,pn)` for purposes of applicability to N args. So it always applies and is not as specific as the fixed-arity method.

So that's the normal reason your `f(a,b)` is more specific than `f(P*)`.

For the one-arg case, it depends on what you pick for the type param.

`f[A](a: A)` does apply to `(a, b, ...)` by tupling and taking A as a Tuple.

By saying A = Int, then obviously A can't be taken as a Tuple.

Sample confusion about var-arity and how affects specificity:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4728

```
object Foo {
  def apply[T](): Int = 1
  def apply[T](x1: T): Int = 2
  def apply[T](x1: T, x2: T): Int = 3
  def apply[T](elems: T*): Int = 4

  // two or more
  def canonically[T](x1: T, x2: T, rest: T*): List[T] = ???
}

object Test extends App {
  Console println Foo(7)
  Console println Foo[Int](7)
  Console println Foo(7,8)
  Console println Foo[Pair[Int,Int]](7,8)
}
```

You might want to post this question on stackoverload.com, the site where the overloading specialists gather. Your browser may be redirected to overloading-is-evil.com.

Comment: I do not understand how this replies to the OPs question. Please elaborate.

Comment: som, thanks for the explanation. Just for the sake of clarity.. In `Foo(x1: T)`, `T` could be a `Tuple`, tuples and varargs are equally specific, that is why I need to hint the compiler that `T` is not a tuple right?

Comment: Yes, "is as specific as" is a test of whether one method applies to the (hypothetical) args of the other. If the one param type is T or Any, then you can tuple your way into making neither "more specific" than the other. The canonical form for 2 or more doesn't have that problem, but it's harder to use. My quickie idea once was to have syntax f(two_plus: A{2,}) so inside the func you only deal with a Seq.

Comment: Thx @gzm0, I was rushing out the door to Kindergarten on the first go.