# How String class taken high priority than AnyRef while calling with null value?

Tags: scala

Here why String taken high priority than AnyRef while calling with null value?

```
class Test {
  def m1(s: String): Unit = {
    println("String version")
  }

  def m1(o: AnyRef): Unit = {
    println("AnyRef version")
  }
}

object Demo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val t: Test = new Test()
    t.m1("arun")
    t.m1(new AnyRef())
    t.m1(null)
  }
}
```

output

```
String version
AnyRef version
String version
```

Comment: thats because scala compiler will match with lowest subtype available. lowest subtype of AnyRef that matches with null is String

Comment: So, instead of AnyRef, if i replaced with StringBuffer than facing error like, "overloaded method value m1 with alternatives:",  what is mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous Reference to overloaded definition - One vs Two Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829114/ambiguous-reference-to-overloaded-definition-one-vs-two-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

So here is what i feel is happening.
`Null`  is a subtype of all reference types; its only instance is the null reference.
Like any other reference type when the compiler looks to pass `null` into a method it does look for implicits for available conversions to the target type which in this case is `String`. And it appears there is an implicit available for this to avoid running into nullpointer exceptions.

If you print out the string inside the  `def m1(s: String): Unit` method you would see there is no exception caused because of this passing.

The other method `def m1(s: AnyRef): Unit` would only execute if there were no available conversions.

Answer (score 0):

The Scala compiler is looking for the lowest common subtype available. 
In your case it is `String`, since `String` is a subtype of `AnyRef`.
Here is Scala type hierarchy:

[image]